# Facebook error when posting on wall from Android. Strange sites appear

Tags: android, facebook

Good morning everyone,
I've got an issue when trying posting on my facebook wall from an application developed on an Android phone.
Here's the problem: Sometimes different "strange" error message appear like "error with HelloIdahoFalls.com" or "HelloSiouxCity.com" or "HolyPlanets Connect" and so on.
I really don't know why these sites appear on my error log. Seems like my Android KeyHash is in conflict with some of this sites.
The strange thing is that sometimes my application works and posts correctly on my wall.
Any idea?
Hope I've been clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am seeing the exact same thing. Random and "UFOS on Earth" type of sites. works, then just fails. On Device or in emulator.

The same problem happens with the Facebook SAMPLE Application (Simple) So i'm thinking this is a facebook server error, and perhaps a pretty big one?